# What is the difference between ==~ and != in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, syntax, comparison, logical-operators

What is the difference between these?

Why use one over the other?

```
def variable = 5
if( variable ==~ 6 && variable != 6 ) {
  return '==~ and != are not the same.'
} else {
  return '==~ and != are the same.'
}
```

Comment: It's not `==~`, it's `==` and `~`. At least in Java. Are you talking about Java or Groovy?

Comment: I'm talking about Groovy, oops.

Comment: When looking at the documentation, can you highlight what is unclear about their difference? http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In groovy, the `==~` operator (aka the "match" operator) is used for regular expression matching. `!=` is just a plain old regular "not equals". So these are very different.

cf. http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html

Comment: Does `==~` as a match operator apply to `variable ==~ 6`?

Comment: Good question actually. Usually regular expression matching requires slashes, but a short test with `def var = 3;` resulted in: `var ==~ 4;` being `false` and `var ==~ 3;` being `true`, so there might be some kind of special handling. I'm no groovy expert though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis To finally shed some more light on this question: The slashes in groovy are _not_ a special requirement for patterns but instead just another way of declaring a string. So `/foo/` is in fact the same as `"foo"`. And I believe that groovy simply treats the `6` as `"6"` (as the variable is an untyped `def`).

Answer (score 12):

In Java, `!=` is *“not equal to”* and `~` is *"bitwise NOT"*. You would actually be doing `variable == ~6`.

In Groovy, the `==~` operator is *"Regex match"*. Examples would be:

1. `"1234" ==~ /\d+/` -> evaluates to `true`
2. `"nonumbers" ==~ /\d+/` -> evaluates to `false`

Answer (score 7):

In Groovy you also have to be aware that in addition to `==~`, alias "Match operator", there is also `=~`, alias "Find Operator" and `~`, alias "Pattern operator".

All are explained [here](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html).

`==~` result type: `Boolean`/`boolean` (there are no primitives in Groovy, all is not what it seems!)

`=~` result type: `java.util.regex.Matcher`

`~` result type: `java.util.regex.Pattern`

I presume the Groovy interpreter/compiler can distinguish between `~` used as a Pattern operator and `~` used as a *bitwise NOT* (i.e. its use in Java) through context: the former will always be followed by a pattern, which will always be bracketed in delimiters, usually `/`.